# Xamarin iOS EC Encryption SECP256r1 with SHA256 Digest Public key length

Tags: c#, ios, security, xamarin, encryption

I'm implementing biometric authentication with public and private keys.

During the instantiation of the key pair, the public key is saved on the server and the private key is saved in the keystore on the device.

Then a challenge is sent to the device, signed by the private key and verified on the server with the public key.

I was able to implement it in Xamarin.Android with the following to generate the key pair:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.GetInstance(KeyProperties.KeyAlgorithmEc, "AndroidKeyStore");
keyPairGenerator.Initialize(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(alias, KeyStorePurpose.Sign)
            .SetDigests(KeyProperties.DigestSha256)
            .SetAlgorithmParameterSpec(new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1"))
            .SetUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
            .Build());
keyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();
```

I get the byte array representation of the public key with `publicKey.GetEncoded()`.
The result is a byte array of length `91`, which is then translated to Base64 string of `124` characters.

Now I am trying to implement the same functionality in Xamarin.iOS with the following:

```
using (SecAccessControl access = new SecAccessControl(SecAccessible.WhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly, SecAccessControlCreateFlags.BiometryCurrentSet | SecAccessControlCreateFlags.PrivateKeyUsage))
{
    SecKeyGenerationParameters parameters = new SecKeyGenerationParameters
    {
        KeyType = SecKeyType.EC,
        ApplicationTag = alias,
        CanSign = true,
        AccessControl = access,
        TokenID = SecTokenID.SecureEnclave // secp256r1?
    };

    SecKey.GenerateKeyPair(parameters.Dictionary, out SecKey generatedPublicKey, out SecKey generatedPrivateKey);   
}
```

I get the byte array representation of the public key with `publicKey.GetExternalRepresentation().ToArray()`, however the array length is only `65`, translated to `88` character long Base64 string.

I tried changing the length of the public key with `KeySizeInBits`, but whatever size other than `256` causes `generatedPublicKey` and `generatedPrivateKey` to be `null`.

Why am I getting a public key with different length?

Comment: 1. Per [SecTokenID Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/security.sectokenid?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12), I think `SecureEnclave` represents `secp256r1`. 2. What is the expected length of `publicKey.GetExternalRepresentation().ToArray()`? `91`?

Comment: Yes, that is what the Android implementation provides. I think it has something to do with a constant header. The Base64 string always starts with "MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found a very old [thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/8030?page=2) and one of the comments pointed me to a solution:

> By trial and error I discovered that I had to add a standard ASN.1 OID
> header to the raw public key bytes

By generating a couple of public keys with the `Android` implementation, I saw that all of them start with the same characters.

```
MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE
```

The `iOS` public key was `91-65=26` bytes short, so I took the first identical `26` bytes from the `Android` public keys, and then concatenated them and the `65` byte public key from the `iOS` implementation to get a `91` byte public key.

Server side confirms the public key is in the correct structure and now everything works as intended.

I hope I'm not screwing anything up as I'm not an encryption expert, but if it's a standard header I guess it's ok.

The implementation if anyone is interested:

```
private readonly byte[] ASN1_HEADER = new byte[] { 48, 89, 48, 19, 6, 7, 42, 134, 72, 206, 61, 2, 1, 6, 8, 42, 134, 72, 206, 61, 3, 1, 7, 3, 66, 0 };

private byte[] ConcatenateHeaderToPublicKey(byte[] publicKey)
{
    byte[] result = new byte[ASN1_HEADER.Length + publicKey.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(ASN1_HEADER, 0, result, 0, ASN1_HEADER.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(publicKey, 0, result, ASN1_HEADER.Length, publicKey.Length);
    return result;
}
```